# Javascript window.open firefox/chrome issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, window.open

I've application to open popup window to print page.

```
function printHTML(urlPath) {
    var printPopUp = window.open(urlPath,null,"height=600,width=777,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes");
    printPopUp.print();
}
```

This script is working fine in IE, but in firefox/chrome. `print()` function is overlapping `window.open`, as a result the print dialog is showing first while screen is still loading. I need to close print dialog in order to render the page properly then print manually.

Please advise.

Comment: are the urls that you will be printing in the same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in your comment, the urls to print are on the same domain.  You cannot access the content of the other windows so you will have to set up some code on the popped up window that will call the opener to tell it it has opened.

popup.html

```
<script>
function onLoad() {
  if(window.opener && window.opener.popupLoaded) {
    window.opener.popupLoaded();  
  }
}
</script>
<html onload="onLoad();">
```

main.html

```
function popupLoaded() {
  popup.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run print after the page is loaded, e.g.

```
printPopUp.onload = function() { printPopUp.print() }
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest calling `window.print()` in the page being loaded into the pop-up rather than in the opener.

Comment: can't because this is global script, its shared on all pages. If i'm doing that way, i need to duplicate code on all pages.